# the jquery unbind events makes the function work once but event is repeated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

this is my main page where i have radio button which when clicked a value will be passed via ajax and the result is checked by ajax and the corresponding output is displayed for each question correct/Incorrect. And the problem is my unbind event is working fine once i click on radio button answer is checked and result is displayed and nothing happens when i click again but the problem is click event is not removed i can click again and again thought the function is working fine and only once.

So how do i make it not click able once clicked ,where is the problem

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<link href="<?php echo base_url('css/style.css');?>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('javascript/jquery.js');?>" rel="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>  
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="main-content">

<?php foreach($result as $rows):?> 
<form>  
 <div class="question-box"> 
 <?php  echo '<h1 class="Qbanner">Q.</h1>'.'<h2>'.$rows->question.'</h2></br>';?>
                        <input  type="radio" name="<?php echo $rows->question_id;?>" value="a"><?php echo $rows->option1;?>
                        <input  type="radio" name="<?php echo $rows->question_id;?>" value="b"><?php echo $rows->option2;?>
                        <input  type="radio" name="<?php echo $rows->question_id;?>" value="c"><?php echo $rows->option3;?>
                        <input  type="radio" name="<?php echo $rows->question_id;?>" value="d"><?php echo $rows->option4;?>

                         <h5 class="result"></h5> 
                       </div>
                     </form>


                 <?php endforeach;?>
            </div>               
    </div>      
<!-- wrapper div ends -->

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var clickedval,qid; 
    $("input:radio").bind('click',function(e){

    clickedval=$(this).val();
    qid=$(this).attr('name');
    var siteurl='<?php echo site_url();?>' + '/site/checkAnswer';

    $this=$(this).parent("div.question-box");
        $allradio=$(this).parent("div.question-box").children();

    $.ajax({
    url:siteurl,
    dataType:'json',
    type:'post',                                                   data:{'answer':clickedval,'questionid':qid},
success:function(data){ 

$this.find('.result').html(data.resultstatus);

$allradio.unbind('click');  
    }   

});
}); 
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Per http://api.jquery.com/bind/ "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document."

Comment: Why did you roll this back to version 1? It is now unreadable again.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it by adding $(this).prop('disabled', true) to your click event function.